# Find all continuous functions (if they exist) $ f \colon Y \to \mathbb{R} $ so that $ f(y) =0, \forall y \in [0, 1) ×\left\{\frac{1}{2} \right\}$

Tags: general-topology

Let $ X = [0,1]^{2}$  be a topological space with with order topology ( lexicographic order) and $ Y= [0, 1) ×\left\{0,\frac{1}{2} \right\}\subset X$ a subspace of $X$. Find all continuous functions (if they exist) $ f \colon Y \to \mathbb{R} $ so that $ f(y) =0, \forall y \in [0, 1) ×\left\{\frac{1}{2} \right\}$

I guess I would have to use Urysohn's theorem or Tietzes? I am not sure where to start. Any hint helps!

Answer (score 1):

A natural continuos map from $Y$ to $\mathbb{R}$ will be the constant map $0$. Another continuos maps will be the following maps:

for each continuos map $f: [0,1)\times \{0\}\to \mathbb{R}$ the map

$h: Y\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $h(x):=0$ if $x\in [0,1)\times \{\frac{1}{2}\}$ and $h(x):=f(x)$ if $x\in [0,1)\times \{0\}$.

This map is continuos because you can observe that $[0,1)\times \{\frac{1}{2}\}$ and $[0,1)\times \{0\}$ are open in $Y$, their union cover $Y$ and their intersection are empty so by gluing lemma you have that $h$ is a continuos map.

By other way for each continuos map $h: Y\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $h=0$ on $[0,1)\times \{\frac{1}{2}\}$  you have that

$f:=h|_{[0,1)\times \{0\}}$ is a map that induces the same map $h$ when you use the gluing lemma so

The set of all continuos maps from $Y$ to $\mathbb{R}$ such that are $0$ in $[0,1)\times \{\frac{1}{2}\}$ is in bijection with the set of all continuos maps from $[0,1)\times \{0\}$ to $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Why is $ [0, 1) ×\left\{0\right\}$ open in Y? Can you explain please because I cant find an open set in X which when intersected with Y gives $ [0, 1) ×\left\{0\right\}$.

Comment: A=(-\infty,1)\times (-\infty, \frac{1}{2}) is open in R^2 so B=A\cap [0,1]^2=[0,1)\times [0,\frac{1}{2}) is open in $[0,1]^2$ then  $B\cap Y=[0,1)\times \{0\}$ is open in $Y$

Comment: That is true, but topology on X is not defined here as relative topology on X as a subspace of $ \mathbb{R^2}$, but as order topology where open sets are intervals  and half open intervals if they contain the maximum or minimum.

Comment: You’re right but in any case B is open with respect that Topology